# Create image augmentations with tf.data.Dataset to produce different augmentations with every epoch

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset fetched from tfds, I want to create normal random rotates on the images that would change with every epoch

This is the current pipeline i use
where should i place the .map(random_rotate) in this pipeline to make the augmentations change with every epoch

```
ds_train = ds_train.map(scale, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples).batch(batch_size).prefetch(AUTOTUNE).repeat()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any random augmentation operation that you use should be placed after the `cache()` method of your data set. `cache()` will save your data and every subsequent call to the data set after one epoch will be to the cache location. That means operations that happen before the `cache()` will not be called again. If your rotation augmentation only works with one image at a time, place the `map()` after `cache()` but before `batch()`. If your rotation augmentation works with batches of images, then you can place it after `batch()` but before `prefetch()`.

Comment: Can you advise about .repeat() as well?

Comment: Are you sure this is right? Don't we need to run map again after each epoch?